# How to print the first line of column 1 and the last line of column two based on the uique identifier in column 3

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I have a tab delimited file that looks like this:

```
Het 157709  157731  Cluster.90  2   +
Het 157739  157760  Cluster.90  2   +
Het 164238  164259  Cluster.97  10  +
Het 164380  164401  Cluster.97  10  +
Het 164396  164417  Cluster.97  10  +
Het 164397  164421  Cluster.97  10  +
Het 164397  164420  Cluster.97  10  +
Het 164399  164420  Cluster.97  10  +
Het 164536  164561  Cluster.97  10  +
Het 164576  164598  Cluster.97  10  +
Het 164599  164615  Cluster.97  10  +
Het 164635  164656  Cluster.97  10  +
Het 198007  198031  Cluster.125 3   +
Het 198007  198028  Cluster.125 3   +
Het 198011  198035  Cluster.125 3   +
```

I am looking for an efficient way to produce a file like the following:

```
Het 157709  157760  Cluster.90  2   +
Het 164238  164656  Cluster.97  10  +
Het 198007  198035  Cluster.125 3   +
```

Where for each unique entry in column 4, I write a line which includes the first line for columns 1 and 2 followed by the last row in column 3, 4, 5 and 6. So far I've tried the following solution but it seems very inefficient:

```
for i in `awk '{print $4}' filename | sort | uniq`
    do
    fgrep -F $i -w filename | awk 'NR==1 {printf $1"\t"$2"\t"} END {print $3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6}' >>filename2
done
```

The problem is, when I have a huge file (487559 lines), this takes forever. Is there a better solution hiding in someone's head out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in single awk which will be much more efficient than your script:

```
awk '!($4 in a){a[$4]=$1 FS $2; r[++i]=$4; b[$4]=$3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6; next;} {b[$4]=$3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6; next} END{for (k=1; k<=i; k++) print a[r[k]], b[r[k]]}' OFS='\t' file
Het 157709      157760 Cluster.90 2 +
Het 164238      164656 Cluster.97 10 +
Het 198007      198035 Cluster.125 3 +
```

To make it readable:

```
awk '!($4 in a){
    a[$4]=$1 FS $2;
    r[++i]=$4;
    b[$4]=$3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6;
    next;
}
{
    b[$4]=$3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6;
    next;
}
END {
   for (k=1; k<=i; k++)
       print a[r[k]], b[r[k]]
}' OFS='\t' file
```

Comment: Somewhat shortened: `awk '!($4 in a){a[$4]=$1 FS $2; r[++i]=$4;} {b[$4]=$3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6;} END{for (k=1; k<=i; k++) print a[r[k]], b[r[k]]}' OFS='\t' file`. But it is still unnecessarily RAM hungry

Answer (score 3):

This one-liner will only work if the unique entries in column 4 always have the same data in columns 5 to the end. Your example is like that, but it doesn't seem to me to actually answer the question. Still, FWIW:

```
paste <(uniq -f3 file | cut -f1,2) <(tac file | uniq -f3 | tac | cut -f3-)
```

`uniq` has an option which controls the number of characters to compare for uniqueness, as well as the number of leading fields to skip and the number of leading characters to skip, but not for the number of fields to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way with `awk`:

```
awk '
!seen[$4]++ { 
  col[$4] = $1 FS $2; 
  fld[++i] = col[$4] 
}
{ 
  sub(/([^ ]+ +){2}/,x); 
  line[i] = fld[i] FS $0 
} 
END { 
  for(x = 1; x <= i; x++) 
    print line[x] 
}' OFS='\t' file
```

Output:

```
Het 157709 157760  Cluster.90  2   +
Het 164238 164656  Cluster.97  10  +
Het 198007 198035  Cluster.125 3   +
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is slow because you are firing off `fgrep` and `awk` processes for each group.

You can simply process your whole file in one pass, after sorting on column 4, of course, which you already know how to do.

So just write in bash, python, ruby, perl, awk or any language of your choice which reads line by line from stdin, and records the last seen value in column 4.  Whenever this value changes, do what you need to do: write out the line containing the first seen values in the first two columns and the last seen values in the later columns.  Then record the new values for column 1 and 2.  It's pretty straightforward but might be tricky around the first and last lines.